# Why is everything taking so long to craft nothing?

Tags: happy-street

My workshop, as well as Nyok's house, is taking about two days to craft nothing. It doesn't tell what's being crafted and doesn't have a status bar above it. What's up with that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to happen when you change your device's system time. As a result of turning the time forwards, items speed up. Turning time backwards makes everything take longer. This concept is found in many games for handheld devices.